# Getting road info from Google Maps API 2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to receive roads information from Google Maps API like the regular street info.

For example, in the Google Maps application, you can see the traffic in each road. Is there any way to receive this info in data and not just view on the screen?

I need to get information such name, traffic, speed-limit and point of start and end.

I think about something similar to the existing streets info, I will give a location (long,lat) and the system will return the nearest roads around (maybe crossroads also).

Is there any way to get this information with Google Maps API? If not, there is another service that can provide this info?
I tried to find some details but I can't find anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) for this. It provides you closest directions, distance and time to travel. I also recommend using [Google-Directions-Android](https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android) library for parsing all that stuff, it really saves a lot of time.